# Groovy equivalent to JavaScript isFinite()

Tags: javascript, groovy

`isFinite(args)` is a javascript function that returns true if `args` can be an integer

```
> isFinite(3)

=>> true

> isFinite("3")

=>> true

> isFinite("az")

==>> false
```

My question is: what is the groovy equivalent of isFinite()?
if no equivalent, what is regex that satisfy isFinite()

Comment: I think your understanding of the purpose of `isFinite()` is a little off: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isFinite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to check something is or can be an Integer (and not that it's finite as with the Number.isFinite method), you could do:

```
def isInteger( a ) {
    a instanceof Integer || a instanceof String && a.isInteger()
}

assert isInteger( 3 )    == true
assert isInteger( '3' )  == true
assert isInteger( 'az' ) == false
assert isInteger( 4.5 )  == false
```

Answer (score 1):

```
assert "3".isNumber()
assert !'ABC'.isNumber()
```

Is what you are looking for? This cannot be used to check Integers, @tim's approach will be useful in that case.

Comment: There's no `isNumber` method on Integer :-( -- heh... too slow ;-)

Comment: @tim_yates duh. You are correct. Slow I am, I have to come out from meetings early. :P

Comment: I know the feeling ;-)